# Intercepting events and controlling behaviour via events for BPEL runtime engine

Tags: bpel

I would like to 
1. intercepting events and 
2. controlling behaviour via events for BPEL runtime engine. May I know which BPEL runtime engine support this?

For 1. for example when an invocation to a service name "hello", I would like to receive the event "invoke_hello" from the server.

For 2. for example, when the server has parallel invocation of 3 services, "invoke_hello1", "invoke_hello2" and "invoke_hello3", I could control the behaviour by saying I would only allowed "invoke_hello1" to be run.

I am interested if there is any BPEL engines that supports 1, or 2, or both, with its documentation page that roughly talked about this (so I could make use of this feature).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve? What kind of events are you thinking of and how do you want to process them? This varies a lot from engine to engine.

Comment: @joergl I have modified the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I haven't personally used the eventing modules of these engines, so I cannot guarantee that they work as they promise.*

### Concerning question 1 (event notification):

**Apache ODE** has support for [Execution Events](https://ode.apache.org/ode-execution-events.html). These events go into its database, and you have several ways of retrieving events. You can:

1. query the database to read them.
2. use the engines [Management API](https://ode.apache.org/management-api.html) to do this via Web Services
3. add your own event listener implementation to the engine's classpath.

ODE's events concern the lifecycle of activities in BPEL. So your "invoke_hello" should map to one of the `ActivityXXX` events in ODE.

The **Sun BPEL Service Engine** included in OpenESB has [some support for alerting](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=BPELProcessLoggingAndAlerting), but the documentation is not that verbose concerning how to use it. Apparently, you can annotate activities with an alert level and events are generated when an activity is executed.

### Concerning question 2 (controlling behaviour):

This is hard and I am not sure if any engine really supports this in normal execution mode. One straight-forward way of achieving this would be to execute the engine in debug mode and to manually control each step. So you could skip the continuation of "invoke_hello2" and "invoke_hello3" and just continue with "invoke_hello1".

As far as I know, ODE does not have a debugger. The Sun BPEL Service Engine on the other hand, [has quite a nice one](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=TestingAndDebuggingBPELProcesses). It is integrated in the BPEL editor in Netbeans which is a visual editor (that uses BPMN constructs to visualize BPEL activities) and lets you jump from and to every activity.

Another option would be to manually code your own web service that intercepts messages and forwards these to the engine depending on your choice. However, as I understand your question, you would rather like an engine that provides this out of the box.

Apparently Oracle BPEL [also has support for eventing](http://blog.vennster.nl/2012/11/eventing-hello-world.html) and [according to this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/matjaz-bpel1-090575.html) also comes with a debugger, but I haven't used this engine personally so far, so I won't include it in this answer.